# How to implement student and teacher relation in OOP

Tags: java, class, oop

I have 2 classes, Student and Teacher. In student i need to display list of teachers who teach that student and in Teacher class i need to display list of students whom they are teaching... How to implement this with OOP concept.

Comment: We will not do the (home)work for you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Its not home work.. I know its very easy to implement in MySQL... With a new relation with 2 FKs. One store student pk and other store teacher pk... so we can select with both ids... But how to implement it in OOP.

Comment: Well, the problem is, neither `Student` nor `Teacher` are actually related in any real way, instead, they bridged by `Subject` (or class is taken), so a `Student` would be taking 1 or more `Subject`s and a `Teacher` would be teaching 1 or more `Subject`s

Comment: OOP is not meant for data modeling, it's meant to decompose systems into interacting state machines. If you're building a school information system, students and teachers are the subjects of facts that your system must record and process. Use OOP to model system services that know of and talk about students and teachers. Information systems aren't domain simulations.

Answer (score 2):

composition is your best friend.

Create class School, which will hold all the information.

School should have list of teachers and students and Subjects, where each subject has one teacher and list of students.

Now you can easily implement showTeachers(Student student) and showStudents(Teacher teacher) methods in School that go through subjects and finding the information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to model that extend it by a class "Course"

```
class Student {
  private Course[] courseTheStudentsIsIn;
}

class Teacher {
  private Course[] courseTheTeacherTeachesIn;
}

class Course {
  private Teacher teacher;
  private Student[] students;
}
```

Then you can search over all courses where the teacher is in if you have a student and wice versa.

Greetings Pascal

Comment: class Teacher
{
    private final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Student
{
    private final List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
}

What's the problem with this... Why course class

Comment: The course class gives you one entry point where you find all your teachers and all your students in.

Comment: You can also give it more layer, like a school (from libik s answer) where you store all courses in to have them grouped as well. (Then you can group all schools in the country, then all countrys on earth and so on...)

Comment: If you have a list of courses then you can just do that to find all teachers and wice versa :           public ArrayList<Teacher> getAllTeachersFromStudent( Student student) { 
    ArrayList<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for(Course course : courses){ 
        if(Arrays.asList(course.getStudents()).contains(student)) { 
            teachers.add(course.getTeacher()); 
        } 
    }
    return teachers;
}

Comment: Actually i am thinking about redundancy problem... We can't avoid it here in OOP... isn't it? Any change in teacher with student relation (like one teacher stops teaching a student) need to change at-least in 2 classes... if we use any methods... Isn't it

Comment: Yes and no, cause we are passing references to objects and not objects themself each change is replicated over (if designed right). If you store a object a in an variable in object b and from outside you manipulate object a, then "the object a in object b is also changed". It's in quotationmarks cause we have no object a in b , but we have a reference to object a in the reference to object b, you understand?

Comment: Wow... It's clear now... Thanks

Comment: You welcome. :)

Comment: If a student stopped studying a course it need to edit both in student class and course class... Is it a data redundancy...

Comment: Thats why I said yes and no. The only way to get around this would be a central list of all courses, then you have to query over all courses and filter out student and teachers which could be very bad if you have a huge amount of data to query. So you need to evaluate on amount of data to query vs small amount of redundancy. No redundancy at all is possible but often not the best solution